# How can I resolve an error on Wordpress after PHP update

Tags: plugins, errors

[image: That's the error]Am having an issue with my website after the new php update it was at first with plugin which I removed via the Control panel but it's still showing an error. See attached picture

Answer (score 0):

1. re upload wp-install & wp-include folders
2. Ensure WP_CONTENT_DIR is defined in your wp-config.php file. It will be the path to your wp-content directory.

   define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content');

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/369614/87704

Credit : @cloudcreatordotio